# Edit Mode lateral bar is empty

Tags: edit-mode

I dont know what happened but before this, i couldnt switch between edit mode and object mode
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Right click on one of the options and click on edit source. Check if there are all the options in the Script and if not, then Copy paste the script and run it again, maybe that will solve the problem.